# Three-gap problem, easy version.

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, trigonometry, contest-math, diophantine-approximation

Let $N$ be a positive integer and $\theta$ an angle in $(0, 2\pi)$. Consider the map$$f: \{0, 1, 2, \dots, N-1, N\} \to  \text{unit circle}, \text{ }f(k) = k\theta \text{ }(\text{mod } 2\pi).$$Show that the image of $f$ divides the circle into arcs of $1$, $2$, or $3$ different lengths.

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have an informal understanding of why the statement might be true? Here is an exercise to try: draw a picture. As you go around the circle the first time you have arcs of just one length that you mark off, and one arc at the end. The situation becomes more complex the second time around. Can you show that things don't get worse as you go around additional times, marking off $\theta$ each time?